# How to display the html-tag through the condition if hugo?

Tags: hugo, go-templates

I have a code in the hugo template engine that should add a script if the parameter in the article is equal to the desired value.

Front Matter articles. Here I need the header_class parameter

```
---
title: "Replaced header"
header_class: "replaced-header"
---
```

If header_class = "replaces-header" output the code. I tried to implement it like this:

```
{{ if isset .Params.header_class "replaced-header" }}
<script>
    let replacedHeader = document.querySelector('.replaced-header');
    window.onscroll = function() {
        let breakPoint = 100;
        let scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if(scroll > breakPoint) {
            replacedHeader.classList.add('replaced-header--scrolled');
        }
    };
</script>
{{ end }}
```

The code doesn't work. How should a condition be set in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Got a reply on another forum, post it here. Any of these three methods will work:

```
  {{ if isset .Params "header_class" }}
    {{ .Params.header_class }}
  {{ end }}

  {{ with .Params.header_class }}
    {{ . }}
  {{ end }}

  {{ with .Param "header_class" }}
    {{ . }}
  {{ end }}
```

Or like this:

```
{{ with $.Param "header_class" }}
{{ if ( eq . "replaced-header") }}
My script
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```